# How to convert an array of hash

Tags: ruby

I am trying to convert the following array of hashes:

```
data = [{
  k: [{id: 'abc'}, {id: 'bcd'}, {id: 'cde'}]
  o: [{id: 'ede'}, {id: 'qpl'}, {id: 'ged'}]
}]
```

into this:

```
#<Test:0x00005628978c1e30 @k=['abc', 'bcd', 'cde']>>
```

I did this:

```
class Test
  def initialize(sample)
    sample.each do |k, v|
      self.instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v.is_a?(Array) ? Test.new(v.map do |v| v[:id] end) : v)
    end
  end
end

test = Test.new(data)
# => #<Test:0x00005628978c1e30 @k=#<Test:0x00005628978c1d90 @abc=nil, @bcd=nil, @cde=nil>>
```

I am also trying to convert the hash (commented in data) into something like this:

```
#<Test:0x00005628978c1e30 @k=['abc', 'bcd', 'cde'] @o=#<Test:0x00005628978c1e31 @b=['ede', 'qpl'], @id='teq' >>
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: What's expected if `o` is uncommented in the hash?

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej Thanks for reply. please check updated question. I want to convert `o` into an object too. Sorry if i got it wrong.

Comment: You need some keys for your inner `Test` objects.

Comment: Have you considered redefining the way you work with that data?, I don't see a profit in creating and storing custom object instances as instance variables.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I verified the data. The flat_map works fine for `k: [ {id: 'abc'}, {id: 'bcd'}, {id: 'cde'} ]` but not for nested array of hash `o: [ { b: [ { id: 'ede' }, { id: 'qpl' } ], id: 'teq' } ]` Thanks..

Comment: `data` is *still* not a valid Ruby object. Do you intend to have a comma after `k: [ {id: 'abc'}, {id: 'bcd'}, {id: 'cde'} ]`? That would be an array containing a single hash with two key-value pairs. Or should `data` be an array of two hashes, each with one key-value pair (`[{k: [ {id: 'abc'}, {id: 'bcd'}, {id: 'cde'} ]}, 
    {o: [ { id: 'ede'}, { id: 'qpl'}, {id: 'ged'} ]}]`)? It is extremely frustrating when members submit code without simple testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
data = [{
  k: [{id: 'abc'}, {id: 'bcd'}, {id: 'cde'}],
  o: [{id: 'ede'}, {id: 'qpl'}, {id: 'ged'}]
}]
```

you asked if the following instance of a class `Test` could be created (`#` at beginning not shown and I inserted the comma at the end of the second line):

```
<Test:0x00005628978c1e30 @k=['abc', 'bcd', 'cde']
  @o=#<Test:0x00005628978c1e31 @b=['ede', 'qpl'],
  @id='teq' >>
```

That seems like an odd request, but it could be done as follows.

```
class Test
end

t = Test.new
  #=> #<Test:0x0000000001eb9c58>
t.instance_variable_set("@b", data.first[:o][0,2].flat_map(&:values))
  #=> ["ede", "qpl"]
t
  #=> #<Test:0x0000000001eb9c58 @b=["ede", "qpl"]>
t.instance_variable_set("@id", 'teq')
  #=> "teq"
t.instance_variables
  #=> [:@b, :@id]
t
  #=> #<Test:0x0000000001eb9c58 @b=["ede", "qpl"], @id="teq">

test = Test.new
  #=> #<Test:0x0000000001e9ad58>
test.instance_variable_set("@k", data.first[:k].flat_map(&:values))
  #=> ["abc", "bcd", "cde"]
test
  #=> #<Test:0x0000000001e9ad58 @k=["abc", "bcd", "cde"]>
test.instance_variable_set("@o", t) 
  #=> #<Test:0x0000000001eb9c58 @b=["ede", "qpl"], @id="teq">
test.instance_variables
  #=> [:@k, :@o]
test
  #=> #<Test:0x0000000001e9ad58 @k=["abc", "bcd", "cde"],
  #     @o=#<Test:0x0000000001eb9c58 @b=["ede", "qpl"], @id="teq">>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to achieve this `[#<Test:0x000000000239f830 @k=["abc", "bcd", "cde"]>,
  #    #<Test:0x000000000239f628 @b=["ede", "qpl", "teq"]>]`  as per the sample data.

Comment: I cannot answer that until you correct the expression for `data` in your question.

Comment: I edited my question (at the beginning) to answer the question in your comment. Note that the array given in your comment differs from the one you gave in your question, *which is not a valid Ruby object and needs to be corrected.*

Comment: @CarySwoveland Can you elaborate on `The reason is that all instances of a class have the same instance variables.`? Unless I'm misunderstanding, this isn't true, with empty `Test` class: `[Test.new.tap{|t| t.instance_variable_set(:@k, '123') }, Test.new.tap{|t| t.instance_variable_set(:@b, '456')}]` returns `[#<Test:0x00005614c92f1960 @k="123">, #<Test:0x00005614c92f18e8 @b="456">]` and it is possible to achieve what OP has requested.

Comment: @Marcin, thank you for your comment. I misinterpreted the question but nevertheless my answer was wrong. I've rewritten.